# Using geojson-vt in EPSG:3826

Tags: qgis, leaflet, geojson

I am a newbie to leaflet.js system. And recently, I meet a problem for future development.

We use geojson-vt to handle canvas drawing in the map which is in EPSG:4326. However, for future work, I need to develop system in EPSG:3826, and the first step is using proj4leaflet.js to project coordinate into EPSG:3826 format, and then my problem is, in
such a case, would geojson-vt can still work well via following code snippet:

```
let geojsonvtdata = geojsonvt(geoJsondata);
```

Or there need something more to do another setting for different coordinate reference system.

Comment: [GeoJSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946) only has one CRS, it isn't defined by any EPSG CRS code (it's not EPSG:4326), it is http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84

Comment: Is that mean when geojson data turn into the points in EPSG:4326, since geojson-vt will break down each diagram into slices, then each data in these slices still work in map-screen even I project them into EPSG:3826 format